# Using jRAPL in JUnit unit test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, energy

There are some way of using jRAPL or similar tool for measure energy consumption inside of unit tests?

Something like:

```
public class FooTest{
    @Before
    public void startUp(){
        double beginning = EnergyCheck.statCheck();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
        double end = EnergyCheck.statCheck();
        System.out.println(end - beginning);
    }

   @Test
   public void FooTest(){
        //TODO
   }
}
```

What configuration I should do to be able to use jRAPL this way, using Eclipse IDE?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Having looked a the code, the following might work for a given method, so long as the query took long enough.

```
@Test
public void FooTest(){
    double beginning = EnergyCheck.statCheck();
    //TODO
    double end = EnergyCheck.statCheck();
    System.out.println(end - beginning);enter code here
}
```

There are some issues with using RAPL when the duration of execution is very small. See: http://os.inf.tu-dresden.de/papers_ps/greenmetrics2012-rapl.pdf

The configuration you would need is to run in on Linux, the instructions indicate that you should use the command:

```
sudo modprobe msr
```

which enables the kernel module for monitoring RAPL based instructions.

An alternative tool is: https://github.com/TANGO-Project/code-optimiser-plugin which is currently under development. It can give power values, but has yet to offer a direct way to calibrate the model that it uses to calculate power consumption.